# return value is not ascending

Tags: indexing, aggregate, row, libreoffice-calc

I use this formula in excel and it works as it supposed to be, but it doesn't work with libre calc.

the return value is wrong and it is not ascending also.

```
=INDEX($E$8:$E$16,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($D$8:$D$16)-ROW($D$8)+1)/($D$8:$D$16=$J$7),ROWS(J$13:J13)))
```

Thanks for any hints.

oke i make some progress with this formula, but it wont ascending.
the return value is correct.

```
=INDEX($F$8:$F$16,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($D$8:$D$16)-ROW($D$8)+1)/(IF($C$6=$D$8:$D$16)),ROWS(B$8:B8)))
```

Comment: A common [**XY-problem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)  - you say that something is not working out for you on the way to the goal, but do not say a word about this goal and starting point. It should be remembered that Calс and Excel are different programs. Very similar, but different. For example, division by zero (and the part of the formula `/($D$8:$D$16=$J$7)` will necessarily lead to such a division) are perceived by these programs differently: Excel considers this to be a valid operation, but Calc does not. You may need to take a different approach.